# I am getting error while installing material ui in cmd for react .I am using this command npm i @material-ui/icons and getting following errors ::

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im getting the following errors when installing Material UI icon package:

```
A:\react\reactJS\awesomeapp>npm i @material-ui/icons

up to date, audited 1870 packages in 7s

59 vulnerabilities (47 moderate, 11 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix
[enter image description here][1]
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
npm audit fix
```

If it did't work, try

```
npm install @material-ui/icons --no-audit
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like @material-ui/icons is already installed!.try uninstalling it and reinstalling it

If that does not work try typing npm audit and npm audit fix!
and try again